# Macbook Pro key rubber part broke

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

I have an M1 MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021). I was cleaning my keyboard by removing the keys and trying to clean the dirt underneath. I had already successfully cleaned a few keys, when this happened: I removed key `u` and the little rubber piece that's underneath the keycap which makes contact with the board broke and came off.

[image]

Now, even if I try to put it back in place, the key doesn't work anymore. In fact, if I try to put the keycap back in place, the key stays "down" and doesn't click properly anymore. What's worse, I wasn't able to make the key work even by putting the plastic piece in place and pushing down, unlike the other keys where if I try to do that after removing the key cap, it results in the key typing correctly.

This is what the button looks like if I try to put everything in place:

[image]

You can also hear the sound the key makes when pressed (second key I press in the video), compared to the sound made by the first one, much clickier: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14JRYInHZ3X8A-3girBOq4zSEMpv300OW/view?usp=sharing

I've seen videos of people replacing that rubber part but it looked like it was on older keyboards, and somebody told me I probably have to replace the entire case of my Macbook.

According to the official manual for repair by Apple, if the silicone dune is damaged, the whole top case is to be replaced. However, while I acknowledge that in order to obtain the optimal experience that'd probablt be in order, I can see that the key underneath is still working to some degree, and I'm definitely willing to settle for *some* degree of it working, even if not optimally.

For example, if I lift the transparent sheet that's underneath the butterly scissors using tweezers, a `u` is typed, so it is making contact. I just need a way to have the rubber dune somewhat make contact for the key to work.

Is there any way to get my key to work again without having to change the whole top case of my Macbook?

Comment: I would never clean under the keys, unless they were so clogged with biscuits that they didn't work at all.

Comment: I definitely learned my lesson now. Do you have any advice as to how I could remedy the situation now?

Comment: See if you can find a Mac-for-spares on eBay. Less likely on a new model, admittedly. Find out if other models use the same keyboard type. Or see if anyone sells key kits that include the rubber bits. Otherwise make friends at an Apple Store - maybe they've got a keyboard that's been taken out that they could give you a ring from.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The problem I see with this is that, when I tried to press the rubber piece to see if I could still press the key and make it work, nothing happened. Intuitively, I would've imagined that making contact between the underlying keyboard and the rubber piece would result in the key being typed, but maybe if the rubber piece is damaged that's not the case? I'm just trying to figure out if there could possibly be some other piece damaged, e.g. the underlying keyboard